# WildFly not running pages

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, wildfly-8

I am using WildFly 8.0 and it runs correctly, but when i publish an EAR procject and I run a page it says 404 "not Found" so what's the problem and what should I do to corrrect it?

WildFly 8.0 deploy log look like this:

```
00:06:21,660 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'EAR-gta.ear/gta-web.war#gta-web'
00:06:21,743 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: yessclever-ejb.jar) in 116ms
00:06:21,751 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: gta-web.war) in 125ms
00:06:21,753 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment EAR-gta.ear (runtime-name: EAR-gta.ear) in 128ms
00:06:21,754 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "EAR-gta.ear" (runtime-name: "EAR-gta.ear")
00:06:22,140 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "gta-web.war")
00:06:22,140 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "yessclever-ejb.jar")
00:06:22,855 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for yessclever
00:06:22,875 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016011: Warning while parsing vfs:/D:/Stage tools/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/EAR-gta.ear/gta-web.war/WEB-INF/beans.xml:3 cvc-elt.1 : Déclaration de l'élément 'beans' introuvable.
00:06:22,877 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for gta-web
00:06:23,230 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'EAR-gta.ear/gta-web.war#gta-web'
00:06:23,231 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment EAR-gta.ear
00:06:23,231 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: gta-web
    ...]
00:06:26,815 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment gta-web.war
00:06:26,828 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"EAR-gta.ear\".\"gta-web.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"EAR-gta.ear\".\"gta-web.war\".beanmanager]",
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"EAR-gta.ear/yessclever-ejb.jar#yessclever\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.clever]",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"EAR-gta.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"EAR-gta.ear\".beanmanager]"
]}
00:06:27,064 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment "EAR-gta.ear" with deployment "EAR-gta.ear"
00:06:27,065 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.EAR-gta.gta-web (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."EAR-gta.ear"."gta-web.war".INSTALL] 
      service jboss.persistenceunit."EAR-gta.ear/yessclever-ejb.jar#yessclever".__FIRST_PHASE__ (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."EAR-gta.ear"."yessclever-ejb.jar".POST_MODULE]
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your project? Probably, you `beans.xml` file is corrupted.

Comment: Post your beans.xml, it seems that there is something wrong, see the warning in your log. Next time start the WildFly with locale en, please.